# (Java) Scanning a String and putting it in a two dimensional Array

Tags: java, arrays, string

So im working on a little console game. Now i have a 9 x 9 field with figures on it. It is described through a String. an "X" means that there is a figure, the "," seperates the fields and the / seperates the rows. Now i want to scan through the String and import it in my two dimensional 9x9 Array. Anyone having an idea how to achieve this?

Here is my code so far:

```
package mainpackage;

public class tesmain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // The field with figures saved as a String
        String gamefield = new String();
        gamefield = ",X,X,X,X,X,X,X,/,,X,X,X,X,X,,/,,,X,X,X,,,/,,,,,,,,/,,,,,,,,/,,,,,,,,/,,,X,X,X,,,/,,X,X,X,X,X,,/,X,X,X,X,X,X,X,";

        // the two dimensional Array i want to transform the String to
        int [] [] fieldArray = new int [9][9];  
    }
}
```

Comment: Use [`split("/")`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) and `split(",")`, and plain Java code.

Comment: Please remove `= new String()` and **forget** that `new String()` even exists.

Comment: `int[][] fieldArray = Pattern.compile("/").splitAsStream(gamefield).map(r -> Stream.of(r.split(",", -1)).mapToInt(String::length).toArray()).toArray(int[][]::new);`

Comment: The power of the streams! @Andreas good!

Comment: Out of curiosity: why did you decide to separate rows with `/` instead of a line break?